# If every Prime-Divisor of m is a prime-Divisor of n ist, then φ(mn) = mφ(n)

Tags: totient-function

To show:

If every Prime-Divisor of m is a prime-Divisor of n ist, then φ(mn) = mφ(n).

φ(n) is the totient-function introduced by euler.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are trying to get others to do your homework.

Comment: Also, please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Comment: PLeasse [search first](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cphi%5Cleft(mn%5Cright)%5C%20%3D%5C%20m%5Cphi%5Cleft(n%5Cright)%24) to avoid posting duplicate Q&A's. In this case the best thing to do is to delete the question.

Comment: deleting is not possible anymore

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own answer:

Let $n = p^{a_1}_1 p^{a_2}_2...p^{a_i}_i p^{a_i+1}_{i+1}...p^{a_s}_s$

Every Prime-Divisor of m is a Prime-Divisor of n.
So $m = p^{b_1}_1 p^{b_2}_2...p^{b_i}$

n can have more prime divisors than m, thats why it can have the extra $p^{a_i+1}_{i+1}...p^{a_s}_s$.

We know φ(k) = k $\prod_{p|k} (1-1/p)$

so φ(mn) = mn $\prod_{p|mn} (1-1/p)$
$=mn(1-1/p_1)(1-1/p_2)...(1-1/p_i)...(1-1/p_s)$

also φ(n) $= n(1-1/p_1)(1-1/p_2)...(1-1/p_i)...(1-1/p_s)$

so it follows φ(mn) = m φ(n)

q.e.d

Correct?

Comment: The first three lines are useless.